# Where should this question be asked?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Techniques for simplifying a regular expression **by hand**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13106510/1653609)

Firstly, I'll admit that I'm no completely sure why this question is off-topic. But furthermore, which community does it belong in?

Comment: You do realize that you're talking about a question that's almost two years old, right?  It has an accepted answer with a score of 3... what purpose would be served by reopening it now?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: May still be useful as a "training instance" so that the OP understands what is and what isn't on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut feeling is that it should go to [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), considering that it is mainly a question of theoretical interest, and that the accepted answer basically involves (simple) NFA theory. Here's a similar question on cstheory: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12361/minimizing-size-of-regular-expression

It's off-topic here because it's a mostly theoretical question with no programming problem asked (the author explicitly asked for by-hand rules, not an algorithm or program).

Comment: I'd say it's more for [cs.se] than [cstheory.se], as I don't think it's really a research-level question.